# Calculating Travel Time in Python 3 Issues

Tags: python, time, calculation

So to be quite frank, I am still very new to Python and unfortunately didn't have any other option to take it over the summer, so forgive me if my code is not optimal but believe me I am trying. So what I am trying to do is create a program that asks the user for a departure date, departure time, miles to be traveled, and the speed at which they will travel. The program is to use this information and create an estimated time and date of arrival.

```
        #!/usr/bin/env python3

#Joshua Ryder
#Arrival Date/Time Estimator



from datetime import datetime
import locale

mph = 0

def get_departure_time():
    while True:
        date_str = input("Enter departure time (HH:MM AM/PM): ")
        try:
            depart_time = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%H:%M %p")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid date format. Try again.")
            continue
        return depart_time


def get_departure_date():
    while True:
        date_str = input("Enter departure date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")
        try:
            depart_date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid date format. Try again. ")
            continue
        return depart_date


def main():
    print("Arrival Time Estimator\n")
    depart_time = get_departure_time()
    depart_date = get_departure_date()
    mph = input("Enter miles per hour  ")
    miles = input("Enter miles:  ")
    #arrival_date = depart_date+miles/mph
    #print (arrival_date)



    return



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is what I have so far. As you can see I have tried making some functions to get the departure time, and the departure date. This is where my first issue occurs. This code as I have it typed, although very incomplete, will run. But no matter how I try to type in a time, it doesn't accept it as a proper format. This kinda makes it hard to go any further with my code because this is essentially the very first step. As far as I can tell I have coded the input for the time correctly, but obviously I have made a mistake somewhere. If someone could take a look at my code and at least point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time.

Update: I have fixed the error with entering the time format, and entering the date works fine as well. Now all I am left with is figuring out how to take the miles per hour entered, and the miles to be traveled, and using that to calculate an arrival date. So if anyone has some help to provide for that, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to put a : instead of - in %H-%M

Comment: Ah ok I see, the slideshow that shows how to enter these formats was a little confusing. Thank you.